# How to move shapes along with the cells when sorting by rows in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Background:
I am using shapes to assign multiple colors to a cell.

Example:
To make a cell half yellow and half green. I make the cell green and add a rectangle yellow shape on the top, covering half of the cell.

Problem:
Problem is, when I use "Sort" feature on excel to sort entire rows by dates( i have a column with dates) it obviously moves the colored cells accordingly BUT!! The colored shapes do not move at all.

How can I make colored shapes to move with the cells? is there a way to permanently link the shape with a cell or a row so it moves with the rows?

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Btw, I am using the following code to generate these shapes according to the selected cell.

```
Dim shp As Shape

Set shp = ActiveSheet.shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, Selection.Left, Selection.Top, 25, Selection.RowHeight)
```

Thanks,

Comment: That is true. Thank you for trying

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the key is to have your shape very slightly *inside* the cell. That is, rather than putting it right at the top-left corner with the same height as the cell, place it a point below and a point to the right of the top-left corner with a height 2 points shorter than the cell:

```
Dim shp As Shape

Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, Selection.Left + 1, Selection.Top + 1, 24, Selection.RowHeight - 2)
```

That works for me in Excel (Office 365), I hope it helps you!

Comment: Yup, making shape slightly inside works perfectly! Thank You so much! you are a life savior.

Comment: Hi, @Rehan, I'm so glad that I could help! It looks like the both of us are very new to stackoverflow.com. May I ask you a small favor? I'm trying to build up a reputation on the site and it helps immensely that you voted my answer up (thank you!) but would help even more if you _accepted_ it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Thanks again and have a good one!

Comment: Eh, I'm not sure. I've never actually asked a question on here. It's no big deal.